# Angular - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined - Getting JSON Data

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I get this error message..

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'geoCoord') 
>  at Object.next (customers.service.ts:16:38)

If I give the "lon" and the "lat" variables a fixed Value, like 51.1634 and 10.4477, the function works. So I guess the problem comes from the get request or the way i target the json data.. Can someone help me out?

The Error occurs in this line.. why cant i acces the values?

```
const lon = c.customerAdress.geoCoord.longitudeCoord;
const lat = c.customerAdress.geoCoord.latitudeCoord;
```

My Service looks like this

```
export class CustomersService {
  customers: string = '../../assets/data/customerdata.json';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  makeCustomerMarkers(map: L.Map): void {
    this.http.get(this.customers).subscribe((res: any) => {
      for (const c of res.customerArray) {
        const lon = c.customerAdress.geoCoord.longitudeCoord;
        const lat = c.customerAdress.geoCoord.latitudeCoord;
        const marker = L.marker([lat, lon]);

        marker.addTo(map);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

This is the component where i call the service

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initMap();
    this.customersService.makeCustomerMarkers(this.map);
  }
```

This is my data

```
{
  "customerArray": [
    {
      "customerAddress": {
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "geoCoord": {
          "longitudeCoord": 10.4477,
          "latitudeCoord": 51.1634
        }
      },
      "phone": "0145221551",
      "eMail": "test@trashmail.de",
      "homepage": "www.google.de",
    },
    {
      "customerAddress": {
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "geoCoord": {
          "longitudeCoord": 10.4477,
          "latitudeCoord": 51.1634
        }
      },
      "phone": "0145221551",
      "eMail": "test@trashmail.de",
      "homepage": "www.google.de",
    },
    {
      "customerAddress": {
        "country": "Deutschland",
        "geoCoord": {
          "longitudeCoord": 10.4477,
          "latitudeCoord": 51.1634
        }
      },
      "phone": "0145221551",
      "eMail": "test@trashmail.de",
      "homepage": "www.google.de",
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can easily find the issue by debugging it in dev tools. Go step by step and you will come to know at which step you are not getting the value. Also, remove "," after every value of "homepage" as it is invalid at the end.

Comment: @RavinderKumar I already did that, I added the traversal operator "?" and they helped with the error. Now leaflet throws me an error that lon and lat is undefined. Is there anything wrong in the way I target the objects in the json data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use safe traversal operator `?` like below.

```
const lon = c?.customerAdress?.geoCoord?.longitudeCoord;
const lat = c?.customerAdress?.geoCoord?.latitudeCoord;
```

Comment: This works to solve this error thank you! but now I get a new Error from leaflet that the lon and lat values are undefined. When I console log them there are indeed undefined, do I have to add something to get the numbers?

Comment: You can approve/upvote and accept this as solved and make a new question for that leaflet specific error. Also share the link here for me to look.

Comment: Maybe its the async call due to which the value doesn't pass through. Also call InitMap method inside ngOnInit and let the service be inside the AfterViewInit. I guess the map isn't initialized or Call service before the InitMap().

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to switch InitMap() to ngOnInit, but it made no difference, but the map still works fine so I leave it like that now. 
I think the issue is that the variables "lat" and "lon" are undefined.. even with the "?" operator, when i console.log the variables they are read as undefined.
I've created a new question for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222688/angular-leaflet-error-invalid-latlng-object-undefined-undefined

Comment: Welcome. So call your methods with some delay (setTimeOut) and you will get an idea that its because Leaflet is loaded and by that time your service has not returned any data. Call the service first maybe in ngOnInit and then the other maybe in AfterViewInit etc. Debug it